# Android "could not find class" error

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview, arcgis

I am new to Android programming and working on a project in Eclipse.I tried the first tutorial'HelloWorld',and got this error:

```
Could not find class 'com.esri.android.map.MapView', referenced from method com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld.HelloWorldActivity.onCreate
```

Does there have to be a layout named `MapView`? If so, I do not have in my project. Could you please tell me how can I get it into the project?

I also have all source folders in the project. Even mapview, don't know why it's showing this kind of error. I need help with this project and I need to complete it within a few days, but I'm stuck due to this error and can't proceed. I'm facing this same problem in all my projects, even though every one of them I tried is a sample provided by ArcGIS.

Here is the code:

```
package com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.esri.android.map.MapView;
import com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer;


public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
MapView map = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    // Add dynamic layer to MapView
    map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("" +
    "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    map.pause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    map.unpause();
}
```

}

Comment: `com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld` your package name?

Answer (score 2):

The following pertains to ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 1.1.1 but may also apply to other versions of the ArcGIS Runtime SDK:

1. Right click on your HelloWorld project and select Properties
2. Select Java Build Path
3. On the Java Build Page, Select Libaries tab
4. Ensure ArcGIS for Android library is present
5. If not, select "Add Library" and select "ArcGIS for Android Library Container"
6. Also on the Java Build Page, select Order and Export tab
7. Ensure that the "ArcGIS for Android" class is **CHECKED!!** <-- this could be your issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the sample.  I had to re-add the ArcGIS library to the project several times because Eclipse kept dropping it or it would be classified as a persisted container when the project loaded.

If it was listed as a persisted container I first removed it from the build path

Then to fix it I did the following:  right-clicked on the project name in the PackageExplorer -> click build path ->  add libraries ->  select the ArcGIS library and click next

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not imported the MapView properly, verify you have this import in the HelloWorldActivity.java:

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

And looking at the [Hello mapview tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) it looks like they dont mention this.

In eclipse you can hit Ctrl+Shift+O to update your missing imports.

Comment: import com.esri.android.map.MapView;

i have this import..do i still need a google import?

Comment: Looks to me less like a missing import (ie, compile time) and more like an implementation of com.esri.android.map.MapView is not making it onto the device, that the one that is isn't getting found, or maybe that the implementation of that is broken and failing to load, thus not present when its needed.  Are there any other errors or warnings?  Is there an implementation of this included in the project source or libraries?

Comment: sorry i did not get you..could you please clarify what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Have you defined your own MapView in the com.esri.android.map package?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may take a look:
[Arcgis API for Android](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit11/papers/tech/introduction_to_arcgis_api_for_android.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

i am also a newbie overhere so i am not pretty sure but i think HelloWorldActivity should extend MapActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: Actually that's a sample i'm using...so i'm positive it's right:) thnx for the suggestion anyway:)